# Cannot set 1440p @ 144hz inside windows with GTX 660

Tags: graphics-card, performance, displayport

I'm trying to set 1440p @ 144hz inside windows environment, I don't care about in-game 144fps with that card.

**Setup**

- [n660oc](https://www.gigabyte.com/gr/Graphics-Card/GV-N660OC-2GD/sp#sp) from Gigabyte. It has DisplayPort 1.2, which in theory [supports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Resolution_and_refresh_frequency_limits) 1440p@144Hz easily. The card is OCd to run at 1Ghz, with a core/memory clock at 6GHz.
- The monitor is an AG273QX which definitely [supports](https://eu.aoc.com/en/gaming-monitors/ag273qx) it, even goes to 165Hz.
- The cable is a certified [Club3d CAC-2068](https://www.club-3d.com/en/detail/2430/displayport_1.4_hbr3_cable_m-m_2m-6.56ft./) DisplayPort 1.4 capable of 32.4Gbps, even supports 8K.

[image]

**Problem**

Yet, in windows automatically I am suggested with 1440p@60Hz.

**Steps**

Through NVidia control panel I've set it manually and reached 133Hz, great! How do I proceed now?

The GpuZ utility displays that the link rate between monitor↔gpu is at 5.4Gbps.
[image]

Both the cable and monitor are for sure ok, which only **implies** the card is to blame..
Any help on how do I approach this, would be **greatly appreciated**.

Comment: The graphics card could easily be the culprit - it's 8 years old at this point. I'm surprised that it reaches 133 Hz at that resolution, nobody was trying to do this with consumer hardware back then.

Comment: I'm lacking evidence for this, any sources or utilities to verify this would be really useful

Comment: Evidence for what? Age of the GPU can easily be verified. 720p and 1080p at 60Hz started getting popular around the release of Windows Vista, so 2006/2007. 1080p@144Hz is uncommon even now in 2020. An 8 years old CPU isn't really expected to handle 1440p@144Hz.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sure, gpu age can be no doubted. I was referring to the capabilities. We agree that is unlikely, but we lack evidence.

Comment: According to the table on the Wikipedia page, 5.4Gb/s is more or less equivalent to the the mode RBR. You shouldn't be able to get 1440p@60 if that's true.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with the pixel clock instead: https://web.archive.org/web/20200730010929/https://www.dell.com/community/Monitors/GTX-770-4gb-Unable-to-select-144hz-on-dell-S2716DG/td-p/4710119 (this is a citation on the same page)

Comment: `In addition, individual devices may have their own arbitrary limitations beyond transmission speed. For example, NVIDIA Kepler GK104 GPUs (such as the GeForce GTX 680 and 770) support "DisplayPort 1.2" with the HBR2 transmission mode, but are limited to 540 Mpx/s, only 3⁄4 of the maximum possible with HBR2.[50] Consequently, certain devices may have limitations that differ from those listed in the following tables.`